# I want to save the app so when the user, exits, the uitextfields don't erase to text when the user comes back

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to save the app so when the user, exits, the uitextfields don't erase to text when the user comes back.

When the app is terminated, it erases all the data in the uitextfields.

what do I do?

Comment: Use `NSUserDefaults` to save the data. When the app restarts, load the data from `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: Just save them when the app terminates and load them when the app starts. `NSUserDefaults` is one candidate. Or plist. A bunch of alternatives.

Comment: Read the document about State [State Restoration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/StatePreservation/StatePreservation.html) And you will find a developer video in the 2012 session video section.

Comment: what code do i add by using NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of alternatives, using serialization and its `read`/`write` methods. I think you should have a look at this link : http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/nscoding.

Answer (score 1):

You should save all the values to NSUserDefaults against a key that represents corresponding textFiled. And in appDidFinishLaunching method you should clear all the values. So that when user open the app from terminated state all values gets cleared and display empty textFields.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the text and not the whole uitextfield object you can put all the fields in a NSDictionary and write them as a plist. There is a a lot of support for this strategy and it may be simplest.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html